# How to change codepen.io editor setting to make tab width as 4 instead of 2

Tags: tabs, editor

I'm trying out some code on codepen to share it with others or as poc. I can see that in the editor any tab is given an 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces.

I'm used to have 4 spaces in my coding style.

How can I change codepen.io editor setting to make tab width as 4 instead of 2.

Comment: This should do the trick: http://blog.codepen.io/2015/02/17/prefer-tabs-prefer-spaces-prefer-specify-indentation-width-got-covered/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `settings > click on Behaviours` and change the tab settings to `tab/spaces` and also increase or decrease the no of space or tabs settings.

Have a look at below screen shot.

[image]